# improve efficiencey to remove a character from a string in java

Tags: java, string

--> How can I improve "efficiency of removing a character from a string" in the following code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StringPractice {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a String : ");
    String str;
    str=sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter char to remove : ");
    char ch=sc.nextLine().charAt(0);

    char[] a=new char[str.length()];
//  System.out.println("Parameters : Char : "+ch+"  String : "+str+"\n");

    StringPractice ob=new StringPractice();
    a=ob.removeChar(str,ch);
    String str1=new String(a);
    System.out.println("New String is : "+str1);
}
char[] removeChar(String a,char c){
    char[] ch=new char[a.length()];
    byte count=0;
    for(int i=0;i<a.length();i++){
        if(a.charAt(i)==c){
            count++; 
            continue;
        }
         ch[i-count]=a.charAt(i);
    }

    return ch; 
}
}
```

Comment: For me it seems quite optimized code. It should be faster than standard methods. Is this a hot spot in your program?

Comment: warm up the code, it can run 50+ time faster without changing it if you compile the code first.

Comment: You have a bug that the `char[] ch` is not any smaller if you remove characters from it. I would worry about correctness first and speed second.

Comment: I would remove `char[] a=new char[str.length()];` as you don't use the object.

Comment: yeah olsai,  i was looking for any other better solution

Comment: peter can you please elaborate on the bug you mentioned above !

Comment: Peter i have used object 'a' to store the updated string, just to remind you array of characters and String are two entirely different things. I hope this justifies the code above..... btw I am new to java,

Answer (score 2):

According to me you are writing code to remove a character occurrence from a sting so just replace it with empty string:
Just change this code there is no need of removeChar method:

```
StringPractice ob=new StringPractice();
        a=ob.removeChar(str,ch);
        String str1=new String(a);
```

SOl:

```
str = str.replace(ch, "");
```

To replace All Occurrence:

```
 str = str.replaceAll("ch","");
```

Comment: I am not sure about the indices assigned to the characters in the new String. Moreover, we still need to have a loop in case of multiple occurances in a string. eg if we want to remove 'e' from elephant.

Answer (score 1):

inbuilt String function `replaceAll()` to remove all the occurrences and `replace()` to remove single character.

```
 string = string.replaceAll("c","");
 string = string.replace("c","");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the StringBuilder class which is mutable.

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(inputString);

```html
public class RemoveString {
 
 
 public static void main (String args[]){
  StringBuilder name= new StringBuilder("chandu");
  
  int i= name.indexOf("n");
  name.deleteCharAt(i);
  System.out.println(name.toString());
  
  
 }
```

Comment: The character might appear multiple times.

Comment: yeah. exactly what i was thinking.